# skip errors in for loop (try and except didn't work)

Tags: python, loops, file, for-loop, telegram-bot

that's the code (very simple) , I tried [try & except] and when i got an error the loop stop

```
def sendp (message):
    file = open('id.txt','r')
    for line in file:
        idn = line
        bot.send_message((idn),(text))
        print('Done For',idn)
```

thats with try/except..

```
def sendp (message):
    file = open('id.txt','r')
    for line in file:
        try:
            idn = line
            bot.send_message((idn),(text))
            print('Done For',idn)
        except:
            pass
```

the error I got is:

> 2021-12-22 19:13:20,309 (__init__.py:694 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found"

that means there is some line in the file didn't work with `send` soo i want it to keep checking lines until the file end

Comment: Can you share your attempt with `try` and `except` and the errors you got?

Comment: use `try/except` and `continue` the loop (also possible to use `pass` depending on what you need) but definitely don't use a bare `except:`, except either a specific error or `except Exception as e: print(e)` (or log it) and remember to `close` the file (or better use a context manager (`with`))

Comment: @Mureinik when i use try/except nothing happen! , if i got error it will stop (same)

Comment: @Matiiss don't worry about close and with , thx for your care! ,i don't understand this part 'except Exception as e: print(e)' what do you mean?

Comment: please update your question with the try and except code you have. Also please share the error / stacktrace where the loop stops

Comment: I meant that you would instead of `except` as you have now, have `except Exception as e:` and instead of `pass` then you would have `print(e)`, also that doesn't look like an exception but more like a log entry

Comment: I update the question ! , I really appreciate your help guys!

Comment: Where is that error? What is the output? Provide a [mcve] preferably!